# Vertically stretching a DIV

Tags: html, css

I've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mupersan82/xAgHg/2/

HTML:

```
                <div class="incidentRow">
                <div class="incidentCellLeft">
                    <span class="incidentCellTopLeft incidentId">206 805</span>
                    <span class="incidentCellBottomLeft incidentReferences">15</span>
                </div>
                <div class="incidentCellTopRight incidentSubject">Anders Buch Lassen</div>
                <div class="incidentCellBottomRight incidentDescription ">
                    <span class="multilineEllipseText">Knokler, knokler, knokler! 
                        Burde gå i seng. Burde gå i seng. Burde gå i seng.
                    Burde gå i seng.Burde gå i seng.Burde gå i seng.
                    Burde gå i seng.Burde gå i seng.Burde gå i seng.</span></div>
            </div>
```

I want the grey box on the left to stretch down to the blue border at the bottom of the wrapper div. It should continue to stretch as more content is added in the box on the bottom right. How can this be achieved?

Comment: In your css,have you tried height:100%?

Comment: If you do `float:left;` it stops the object from having any height with the context of its container. Try laying this out using `display:inline-block;` instead and making sure the margins are sensible.

Comment: Yes, I tried with 100% and also display:inline-block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.incidentCellLeft
{
    max-height:200px;
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

`height:100%;` and `position: absolute;` added. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/xAgHg/5/

Besides, you shoudl remove `max-height:200px;` if you want it to be stretched to more than 200px height.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the height of anything. Just set the `background-color` of the container to grey, and the background color of the right cells to white:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xAgHg/9/)

Comment: Thanks, three different solutions so far. Which one is prefered? Or maybe is doesnt matter?